# json data repeating twice in recylerview when reloading app or when opening app

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

can anyone please help me i can not figure out the problem in the code. i only want to load the json response once when application startup or when activity reload but it loading json response twice in recylerview everytime when application start and making two copies of every json object retrive from server in my case there total 50 news channel in recylerview instead of 25 news channel

```
  public class General extends Fragment  
     {

        private static final String
        URL = "https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en&category=general&apiKey=0e1b2f7bc6bd4e1fbe0b40bea257dc97";
        private final int android_image_urls[] = 
      {
        R.drawable.abcnews,
        R.drawable.aljazeera,
        R.drawable.associatedpress,
        R.drawable.bbcnews,
        R.drawable.cnn,
        R.drawable.googlenews,
        R.drawable.independent,
        R.drawable.metro,
        R.drawable.mirror,
        R.drawable.newsweek,
        R.drawable.newyorkmagazine,
        R.drawable.reddit,
        R.drawable.reuters,
        R.drawable.theguardianau,
        R.drawable.theguardianuk,
        R.drawable.thehindu,
        R.drawable.thehuffingtonpost,
        R.drawable.thenewyorktimes,
        R.drawable.thetelegraph,
        R.drawable.thetimesofindia,
        R.drawable.thewashingtonpost,
        R.drawable.time,
        R.drawable.usatoday
   }; 

   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
   private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> androidVersions;

  TextView textView;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_general, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    androidVersions = new ArrayList<>();
    loadRecyclerViewData();
    return rootView;
    }


   public void loadRecyclerViewData() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data....");
    progressDialog.show();


    JsonObjectRequest data = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sources");

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            AndroidVersion item = new AndroidVersion(

                                    o.getString("name"),
                                    android_image_urls[i],
                                    o.getString("category")
                            );
                            androidVersions.add(item);

                        }


                        if (androidVersions.isEmpty()) {
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        adapter = new DataAdapter(androidVersions, getContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    })
    {
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
        if (cacheEntry == null) {
            cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
        }
        final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60*1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
        final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 1000 ; //24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
        final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
        cacheEntry.data = response.data;
        cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
        cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
        String headerValue;
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
        if (headerValue != null) {
            cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");

        if (headerValue != null)
        {
            cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
        }
        cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
        final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), cacheEntry);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
    }
        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
            super.deliverResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
            super.deliverError(error);
        }

        @Override
        protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
            return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
        }
};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(data);
}
```

}

Comment: Clear the ArrayList before adding items to it    androidVersions.clear()
and no use of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() so you can remove this.

Comment: Thank u so much Geeta it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct , it must not show the duplicate data , try removing the caching of data

Comment: rajendra you are write about removing catching of data i try that it works but i want to store at least small amount data in recylerview when app started so that user can view or read some of last successfully loaded data in offline whenever the internet connection is not available so what should i do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In you `onResponse` you are not cleaning the `androidVersions` list. So each time your request is executed you add new items to your list. Most probably your request is executed twice (`loadRecyclerViewData()` is called twice?).

Try to clean or recreate `androidVersions` every time you fill it in `onResponse`.

Comment: Thanks algrid for your solution, but can you please explain me what you said in detail like piece of program to clear list because i am doing this thing for first time

Comment: please tell me how should i achieve what you said programmatically?